# Connection Reset on Google OAuth Credential.refreshToken

Tags: java, google-oauth-java-client

I am attempting to create a credential using a service account (in order to retrieve Google Analytics info).
But when Credential.refreshToken(..) is called, I get a
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

I have created an OAuth service account and a P12 file using the Google Developers Console.
Then I execute the following code:

```
// Create the credential

HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
File p12File = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/analytics/my-project.p12");
Set<String> serviceAccountScopes = Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS);

GoogleCredential.Builder builder = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId("123abc<etc>@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(serviceAccountScopes);

GoogleCredential credential = builder.build();

// Attempt to refresh the credential's token
credential.refreshToken();
```

This results in a short pause, then the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1705)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:909)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1423)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1288)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
<etc>
```

The code is executing in a webapp running on Tomcat.
Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who gets here...
The problem was some kind of firewall issue at work. Everything worked perfectly when I created a Wifi Hotspot through my phone and went through that.